# how to activate two viewControllers of an tabBar View?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to activate Favourites tabBarItem as a child over a parent viewController's AllServices tabBarItem and i want to keep both tabBarItems activated.

Favourites is a collectionView

The image below describe my question.
AllServices is the ParentView controller and Favourites is ChildView
by the way i'm using StoryBoard.

So, please help me.

[image]

Comment: So you want to have a tab bar controller that has a tab with a view controller... and as part of that controller you want an imbedded tab bar controller?

Comment: @datinc, I've add an image it describe my question. check the image, please

Comment: That really really isn't how tab bar controllers are expected or supposed to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't select two tabs of tabbarcontroller at the same time...

In you case,assign allservicesview controller as a root of "favorite" and "all sevices" tab and if it displayed for "favorite" tab,add favoritesview on it as a subview...